# Swing: Cascaded JPanels in GridLayout causes unexpected gap on Resize

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am facing a strange behaviour with cascaded `JPanel`s and `GridLayout`s.

The following demo shows my problem:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JPanelGridLayoutDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JPanel GridLayout Demo");

        int cols = 5, rows = 5;
        int innerCols = 15, innerRows = 15;

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(cols, rows, 0, 0));

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));

                // panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(cols, rows, 0, 0));
                // fixed it as FastSnail suggested
                panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(innerCols, innerRows, 0, 0));
                frame.add(panel);

                for (int innerCol = 0; innerCol < innerCols; innerCol++) {
                    for (int innerRow = 0; innerRow < innerRows; innerRow++) {
                        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
                        innerPanel.setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
                        panel.add(innerPanel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This will display the following panels:

[image: 400x300px (standard size)]

I generally would have not expected to see the background color of the outer panels. `GridLayout` normally behaves with filling the parent container. And so it is, when I resize the panel horizontally to a specific frame width. Then it is displayed as expected:

[image: 436x300px (resized)]

As soon as I resize it again, the gap appears again. It seems like everything is rendering fine when `frameSize % x == 0`, if this helps to understand the problem.

How can I fix this, so that the inner panels always fill out the entire parent container? Do I have to override `GridLayout`?
For me this seems to be a problem with the implementation of `GridLayout` like a rounding problem or something.

---

I fixed the inner `GridLayouts` as FastSnail suggested, the gap is not smaller but still visible:

[image: inner GridLayout fixed]

**Background information/Side question:**

I want to render a visualization similar to this and first thought about pixel-wise rendering. But I want to provide hovering, highlighting, click events and dynamic resizing, therefore I use panels for this case. Do you see any problems in that (except of performance issues)?

Comment: `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(cols, rows, 0, 0));` should be `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(innerRows, innerCols, 0, 0)); `.
in your panels all inner panels have same width and hight .for example you have 15 inner panels horizentally so the width of panel which hold inner panels shoud have length which is multiply of 15 otherwise there should be a gap.

Comment: An don't forget to `pack()`.

Comment: @FastSnail thanks for the improvement, see my updated post. Is there any possibility to enforce the size of the children so that they fill out the entire space?
@trashgod I tried `frame.pack()` but it didn't change anything

Comment: @thunderhook are you still need a help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692893/1213544) (and FastSnail suggested) `GridLayout` produces a gap because of the size calculation of its inner components.

So if you have a `100px` wide panel, its containing 15 panels will get the size of `6px` (`100/15 = 6.67`). The resulting `10px` (`100 - 6 * 15`) result in a gap.

Therefore I changed the `GridLayout` to a `MigLayout` and now it works as expected:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class JPanelGridLayoutDemo  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JPanel GridLayout Demo");

        int cols = 5, rows = 5;
        int innerCols = 15, innerRows = 15;

        // fill, remove margin, remove grid gaps
        frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets 0, gapx 0, gapy 0"));

        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(new Color((int) (Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
                panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, insets 0, gapx 0, gapy 0"));

                // cell position, fill, min-width 1, min-height 1
                frame.add(panel, String.format("cell %d %d, grow, w 1::, h 1::", col, row));

                for (int innerCol = 0; innerCol < innerCols; innerCol++) {
                    for (int innerRow = 0; innerRow < innerRows; innerRow++) {
                        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
                        innerPanel.setBackground(new Color((int) (Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
                        panel.add(innerPanel, String.format("cell %d %d, grow, w 1::, h 1::", innerCol, innerRow));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```